# Read more button not working

Tags: templates, blog, read-more

I want the "read more" button to appear to truncate the blog posts. I tried using the button insert shortcode < !--more-->", but it's not showing up.

I've tried everything I know how...

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

[From the Codex:](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More)

> Excerpts (teasers) can be shown on WordPress through two methods:
>
> - The first, keeping the `the_content()` template tag and inserting a
>     quicktag called more at your desired "cut-off" point when editing
>     the post.
> - The second, by replacing the `the_content()` template tag with `the_excerpt()`.

If one of those conditions is met, and you are not getting the `<!--more-->` functionality then it is likely that your theme is doing something to bypass the the filters that make it work. Perhaps the theme is printing content via something like `echo $post->post_content` or the theme or a plugin has removed filters or added filters that break the `<!--more-->` tag. It is hard to say which without seeing the relevant code.